# how to disable unencrypted traffic(port 80) on lighttpd

Tags: ssl, http, https, lighttpd

We want to run an SSL only lighttpd process. Which configuration option should be used to turn off port 80 with its unencrypted traffic ?

Lighttpd documents only provide a "redirection" to https traffic, but we want a complete silence on port 80. We want to keep lighttpd listening only on 443 for encrypted(https) traffic.

**Update [Solution]**

Setting *only* "`server.port  = 443`" does not help. SSL config was :

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "0.0.0.0:443" {
                  ssl.engine                  = "enable"
                  ssl.pemfile                 = "/etc/cert.pem"
}
```

That gave the error.

```
can't bind to port: 0.0.0.0 443 Address already in use
```

Removing the conditional SSL altogether solved the issue, the config became:

```
server.port                 = 443
ssl.engine                  = "enable"
ssl.pemfile                 = "myweb.pem"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to set server.port = 443 in lighttpd.conf
and comment the conditional $SERVER["socket"] == "0.0.0.0:443" {  }
in 10-ssl.conf

keep `ssl.engine  = "enable"` and `ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/server.pem"` in `10-ssl.conf`

Answer (score 2):

How about, commenting out

```
# /etc/rc.d/lighttpd start
```

Or, you could comment out the `fastcgi.server` lines in

```
/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

---

Ok, this is the reference I was looking for, [are you using these things](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lighttpd_For_Both_SSL_And_Non-SSL)?

I think the bottom line is, if you just make the `server.port` **`443`** and
remove the port 80 config entirely [instead of a redirect](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToRedirectHttpToHttps), the server would respond only on 443.

Comment: we want to disable http traffic and keep only http**s** traffic. We are not even using fastcgi or php.

Comment: Ok, then does the last part I just added work on your configuration?

Comment: changing server port only with the recommended ssl config snippet didn't work. See the question for working solution. thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but still a work around would be to install a firewall such as Iptables and completely block traffic on port 80.

Comment: An `iptables` trick should also stop incoming port-80 traffic. Unless, you want to run something else there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to comment:

```
   include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl"
```

to disable additional SSL pre-configuration.